# how to find if a number has a representation in a powerbase format?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

I better explain this problem with an example, $100$ would be represented as $983$ because $9^1 + 8^2 + 3^3$ is one hundred.

So how to find the relation between the number $n$ and numbers that can be used to represent $n$.

For example if given numbers from $2$ to $7$, the number $25$ can not be represented in a power base format, but if the numbers were from $2$ to $8$ then $25$ would be represented as $832$: ($8^1+3^2+2^3$).

Comment: Suggestion: Change the tag from "complex numers" to something like "recreational number theory".

Comment: got it thanks @coffeemath.

Comment: It is about $n = x^1 + y^2 + z^3$ always and the relationship $n$ and $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: no it isn't @mvw , it could be x^1 +y^2+z^3+...r^d where d is the number of numbers allowed  for example number of numbers allowed from (2 to 7) is 6.

Comment: Given a sum of terms $\mbox{base}^{\tiny \mbox{exponent}}$. You mention a restriction on the possible exponents (e.g. ranging from $1$ to $d$) and a restriction on the possible bases ($8^1$ but not $7^1$). Can you please update your question with precise mentioning of what bases and what exponents are allowed.

Comment: I think he wants to know the minimal set required to solve each $n$, e.g can it be solved with $\{1,2,3\}$ as the base, or does it require all the way up to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. Exponents need to be ascending. Or it seems more than that, perhaps the mimimal set size(seeing him say $2$ to $7$)